# how to close an active document in Mac OS using shell script

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, macos-mojave

I am closing active document using apple script as below

```
  tell application "Microsoft Word"
                activate
                try
                    if not (exists active document) then error number -128

                    close active document saving yes

                on error

                end try
            end tell
```

want to do similar action using shell script. I want to gracefully close it and don't want to use kill command . And I don't want to use osascript to call an apple script . I want a graceful way using native shell commands

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use osascript in the shell code

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript <<EOF
tell application "$1"
  close (every window whose name is "$2")
end tell
EOF
```

Compile this code and make filename.sh

or you can use

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript <<EOF
tell application "Preview"
  close (every window whose name is "$1")
end tell
EOF
```

To use this from cmd type $./file_name Preview application name

Here I used the reference of https://ss64.com/osx/osascript.html

Comment: I don't want to use applescript in any form, I am looking for native shell commands

Comment: @Dutt why?  Firstly, you can't do it without using AppleScript.  Secondly, the solution provided here _does_ use native shell commands, and those shell commands happen to include `osascript`, which takes a text file (or a heredoc) as its argument and executes it as a piece of AppleScript.  What's the problem ?  Or, if by "native" you mean shell _builtin_ commands, then you have absolutely no hope of achieving your desired goal.

Comment: Thank you thats what I want to know @CJK